# c# Maximize Window from System Tray

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-vista, user32, maximize

I am having trouble trying to bring my application window to the front  (i.e on top of all other windows).  I want the user to be able to double click the notifyIcon in the system tray, and If the application already has a window open for it to be bought to the front.  I have tried using the following two P/inovkes but neither seem to work consistently.  Does anybody have any idea how to bring a window to the front/top?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
tatic extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

ShowWindowAsync(ADProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
SetForegroundWindow(ADProcess.MainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: It might be useful to show your interop signatures for the two methods you are P/Invoking.

Comment: Included the interop signatures

Answer (score 0):

Given the little info you have provided the best guess I can make is that you have a timing issue with the call to ShowWindowAsync which runs asynchronously followed by the call to SetForgroundWindow.

Have you tried using ShowWindow to see if that works correctly?

Comment: according to the discussion on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it is better to use the Async-Version if the window is owned by some other process...

Comment: I agree, but it would be a good first test to see if this is a potential timing issue. By testing with ShowWindow you will either eliminate timing as an issue or identify that it is a possible issue and know which direction to investigate next.

Comment: Neither seem to work on vista. Both work on windows 7. I'm sure its a problem caused by the minimize in the external app window.  I dont understand why IsIconic is false when the app is minimised.